# Iterate over single map inside Terraform dynamic block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have the following snippet inside of a resource block,

```
...
condition {
    dynamic "http_header" {
      for_each = var.http_headers
      content {
        http_header_name  = http_header.value.header_name[0]
        values            = [http_header.value.values[0]]
      }
    }
}
...
```

Variable is currently set to:

```
variable "http_headers" {
  type = map
  default = {}
}
```

I'd like to provide a single map and have Terraform set the values for them inside the content block, e.g.

```
http_headers =  {
    header_name = "foo"
    values      = "bar"
}
```

I thought this would work based on reading I've done so far, but I am getting errors similar to the following.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on .terraform/main.tf line 138, in resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "listener_rule":
 138:         values            = [http_header.value.values[0]]
    |----------------
    | http_header.value is "foo"

This value does not have any attributes.
```

FWIW I have been able to get this working if I wrap the `http_headers` variable in a list and iterate over that instead but I would like to simplify the configuration to only use a single map. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have a mix of map and list, if you want to loop over something it should be a list...

I prefer lists with clearly defined objects, that way the input is validated:

```
  type = list(object({
    num    = number
    protoc = string
    values = string
  }))
```

But you could also go with the simpler

```
  type = list(any)
```

Here is an example:

```
variable "http_headers" {
  type = list(object({
    num    = number
    values = string
  }))

  default = []
}

data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "network_acl" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.http_headers
    content {
      rule_no    = ingress.value.num
      protocol   = ingress.value.protoc
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = ingress.value.values
      from_port  = 22
      to_port    = 22
    }
  }
}
```

Then we have the input in a json file (`input.tfvars.json`):

```
[
  {
    "num": 1,
    "protoc": "tcp",
    "values": "10.0.0.1/32"
  },
  {
    "num": 2,
    "protoc": "tcp",
    "values": "10.0.0.2/32"
  }
]
```

Last we can run a plan:
`terraform plan -var-file="input.tfvars.json"`

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_network_acl.network_acl will be created
  + resource "aws_network_acl" "network_acl" {
      + arn        = (known after apply)
      + egress     = (known after apply)
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + ingress    = [
          + {
              + action          = "allow"
              + cidr_block      = "10.0.0.1/32"
              + from_port       = 22
              ...
              + rule_no         = 1
              + to_port         = 22
            },
          + {
              + action          = "allow"
              + cidr_block      = "10.0.0.2/32"
              + from_port       = 22
              ...
              + rule_no         = 2
              + to_port         = 22
            },
        ]
      + owner_id   = (known after apply)
      + subnet_ids = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id     = "vpc-f99999999"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: I probably have remnants in there for getting it working with lists. Is there a way that you know of to use a single map instead of a list of maps?

Comment: @jmreicha if you want to loop over something I don't think a map is the best option, I think it should be a list, if you don't like to defined the object, just use `list(any)`

Comment: That's fair, maybe went down the wrong path with the map approach.

Comment: @jmreicha now just to clarify, we can loop over a map, terraform shows it on their documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html#basic-syntax but I would only use that on very simple cases like that hardcoded example they show